# Does a more complicated neural network necessarily increases the computational time? Why?

Tags: neural-networks

I'm currently new the field of machine learning and neural networks. Been doing some quick tests regarding how a structure of neural network affects the computational time.

below is result of my tests.
(**the network structure is in a format of: input layer, hidden layer 1, hidden layer 2, output layer)

[image]

I can understand for the accuracy drop for the "overfitting" cases, but I don't understand why would a more complicated structure (sample 2.1a) will have the same recognition time as a simpler structure (sample 2.1c)

Any kind of help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In general, what you believe is correct. More complex models tend to have larger recognition times because there are more computations to be done. However, benchmarking should always be done with care. The reported times are the mean values, but there are no components to measure the uncertainty over them (e.g. percentiles, sample sizes).

Secondly, the results are heavily affected by library implementations, such as low level optimisations, multi-threading/processing etc. For example, some configurations might have sparser matrices and computations can be easier. A careful (but probably cumbersome) analysis would spot out a lot of the reasons.

Comment: The results are all with same code environment, same machine, same library. 
But not sure whether the CPU usage might affect the performance as I recall that I did use the same machine to do some other stuff during the tests. 





With that being said, perhaps the "performance per single input" should be calculated through the accuracy test by averaging the time required?

Comment: @StevenWong Other tasks can have an affect depending on their strength in CPU usages. Even if you use the same computer/library etc. you don't know the multi-threading strategy of the specific library implementation. For example, it maybe the case that the number of threads/processes are being determined dynamically wrt the size of the matrices. Finally, I want to underline (as per my first paragraph) the importance of percentiles instead of means to aid your decisions on one configuration being faster or slower than the other. Because you have no measurements over uncertainty.